# Cannot access a disposed object.\nObject name: 'PrimaryToolbarItem'

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a ToolbaItems in a ContentPage that is a ShellContent from FlyoutItem - I am using ShellApp.

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem
        x:Name="xicon"
        Clicked=""
        IconImageSource="{local1:ImageResource MobileApp.Resources.Images.x.png}"
        Text="Saw X" />
    <ToolbarItem
        x:Name="yicon"
        Clicked=""
        IconImageSource="{local1:ImageResource MobileApp.Resources.Images.y.png}"
        Text="Saw Y" />
    <ToolbarItem
        x:Name="zicon"
        Clicked=""
        IconImageSource="{local1:ImageResource MobileApp.Resources.Images.z.png}"
        Text="Saw Z" />
   </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

In Android it works well, but in iOS I got an error:

```
Message "Cannot access a disposed object.\n
Object name: 'PrimaryToolbarItem'." string



$exception  {System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'PrimaryToolbarItem'.
  at Foundation.NSObject.get_SuperHandle () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:469 
  at UIKit.UIBarButtonItem.set_Image (UIKit.UIImage value) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIBarButtonItem.g.cs:827 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ToolbarItemExtensions+PrimaryToolbarItem.UpdateIconAndStyle () [0x00031] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Extensions\ToolbarItemExtensions.cs:84 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021 
  at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at Toretto.MobileApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\Toretto\Toretto.MobileApp\src\Toretto.MobileApp\Toretto.MobileApp.iOS\Main.cs:17 }  System.ObjectDisposedException
```

If I remove theses items in the constructor of the ContentPage it does not crash, I tried to use only Text, in Android I am using icon and works...

```
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)  
        {
            this.ToolbarItems.Clear();
        }            
    }
```

Is this a bug? In github I saw few issue about toolbar.

Comment: "If I remove theses items in the constructor" - where is the code for this?

Comment: I would try moving the code to `OnAppearing`

Comment: Are you saying the I should create the ToolbarItems in OnAppearing method? I am creating in XAML

Comment: no, I misunderstood your original question.

Comment: Only can use text in iOS when create the toolbaritems inside of OnAppearing method... I would like to have icons :( If  I use icon it crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is just the case.  It is a known issue, and xamarin development team have added this to `To do` in `xamarin form v5.0.1`.

You can follow it up here:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6387.

We are sorry for the inconvenience.And thanks for your support for xamarin.

Comment: Thank you to confirm.